WebXR persistent anchors on Meta Quest 3 don't remain fixed in space
I recently purchased my first XR headset and started developing on it. I'm fairly new to XR development, but I found myself stuck with the issue below which I'm unfortunately unable to find a solution for by Googling or basic reverse engineering. Some pointers on how to go forward would be greatly appreciated :)
What I want:

Show virtual items in my room through mixed reality
Expect the items to stay in the same place relative to the real world, regardless of what I do with the headset (e.g. close browser/shutdown headset/take off headset/...).

Relevant tech stack:

Three JS (based on WebXR)
React JS
Meta Quest 3
Libraries

"@react-three/drei": "^9.102.6",
"@react-three/fiber": "^8.16.0",
"@react-three/xr": "^5.7.1",
"three": "^0.162.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",



What I tried:

Get frame:

const getAnimationFrame = useCallback(() => {
 return new Promise<XRFrame>((resolve) =>
   session?.requestAnimationFrame((time, frame) => {
     resolve(frame);
   })
 );
}, [session]);


Create anchor:

const { gl } = useThree();
const { session } = useXR();
let frame = await getAnimationFrame();
const space = gl.xr.getReferenceSpace();
if (!anchor && space && frame.createAnchor) {
  const pose = new XRRigidTransform(
     { x: 0, y: 0, z: -1 },
     { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1 }
  );
let anchor = await frame.createAnchor(pose, space);


Get anchor pose matrix

const frame = await getAnimationFrame();
const space = gl.xr.getReferenceSpace();
const anchorPose = frame.getPose(anchor.anchorSpace, space);
const matrix = new Matrix4();
matrix.fromArray(anchorPose.transform.matrix);


Make anchor persistent

const uuid = await anchor?.requestPersistentHandle();
localStorage.setItem("uuid", uuid);


Restore anchor

const uuid = localStorage.getItem("uuid");
const anchor = await session.restorePersistentAnchor(uuid);

Problem:

Anchor moves. While I expect it to be fixed in space.
It moves:

Sometimes when I move the headset quickly (e.g. remove it from my head)
Sometimes when I put the headset down on the table with the camera's down
Sometimes when I restart the device
...



Question:

Does anyone know why the above problems occur and how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.
